# postgresql latitude longitude belgium

Tags: python, postgresql, localization

I have a table with two columns (real type) for latitude and longitude respectively.
I would like to know if these points are located in Belgium, directly from a SQL query (postgreSQL).
I've already seen some things in python (Geopy) but the number of requests is limited (geopy.exc.GeocoderServiceError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
) ...

Any idea ? 
Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly in Postgres with the PostGIS extension. You would need to store the shape for Belgium in a table.

The function to call is [ST_CONTAINS](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html), which returns True or False if the first geometry contains the second one.

```
SELECT layer_pt.* FROM layer_belgium, layer_pt WHERE ST_Contains(layer_belgium.geom,  layer_pt.geom);
```

The first geometry would be the shape of Belgium and the second one would be your point. You may have to restrict the query to get only Belgium should you have other countries in it.

Since you don't have a point geometry but only its coordinate, you would also have to [create the point geometry](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html) on the fly.

```
SELECT layer_pt.* FROM layer_belgium, layer_pt WHERE ST_Contains(layer_belgium.geom,  ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || layer_pt.y || ' ' || layer_pt.x || ')', 4326));
```

Should you need more help with PostGIS, have a look at the [GIS StackExchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you, it is very helpful !